# Can't install win10toast module

Tags: python, pip

Can't install win10toast module with "pip3 install win10toast". It throws an error:

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-2uu5xb0v/pypiwin32_549d147fa130437585493cbe7016b067/setup.py", line 121
          print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have searched it up online. But the only solution I found was to use pip3 instead of pip. But It still doesn't work. Can someone help me?

tried using different commands like pip3 install win10toast, python3 /usr/bin/pip3 install win10toast. I need solution to install win10toast.

Comment: That usage of `print` is from a very **very** old version of python.  If you can, I recommend removing Python 2 from your computer.

Comment: `win10toast` hasn't been updated since 2018, it's unlikely to work.

Comment: Based on what you say you've tried, it looks like you're trying to install it on Linux.  There's a [reported issue on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/issues/109) with the exact same error message, and the response was "This is ONLY for windows as suggested in the name you may now close the issue".  The underlying issue is that the `PyWin32` module that this depends on [has no valid distribution for Linux](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1177).  `Win10Toast` and `Win11Toast`  should both work in Windows.

Comment: Oh yes I am trying to use it in Linux. The code for this was written from a windows machine, so thats what the problem was. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying cause of your error message is that `Win10Toast` is dependent upon the `PyWin32` module, which does not have a valid distribution for Linux,  and it's setup.py file for some reason still contains this Python2 print statement, which causes the error you saw above.  See also:
https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/issues/109 and
https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1177

`Win10Toast` is also no longer maintained, and you should probably be [using `Win11Toast` instead](https://pypi.org/project/win11toast/), which supports both Windows 10 and Windows 11.
In either case, because the package is reliant on Windows APIs, and other modules using those Windows APIs, it can only be installed on a Windows platform.

Comment: Oh I got it thank you very much.